# Suprema Properties and Real Value Functinos

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: A \to \mathbb{R}$ are real valued functions. Define
$(f+g)[A] = \{f(x) + g(x): x \in A\}$ and $f[A] + g[A] = \{f(x) + g(y): x, y \in A\}$.

What is the relationship between $\sup(f[A] + g[A])$ and $\sup((f+g)[A])$?

Repeat exercise for $\inf(f[A] + g[A])$. Essentially one side is $f(x) + g(x)$ and the other is $f(x) + g(y)$. I am thinking they are equal, but I'm not sure. I need a proof too.

Comment: I'm confused, you have two different definitions for $f(A)+g(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

use that $ \{ f(x) + g(x): x \in A\} \subset \{f(x) + g(y): x, y \in A\}$

Answer (score 0):

So we know that, using your definitions, 
$$(f+g)[A] \subseteq f[A]+g[A]$$ because every element of the right side is an element of the left by setting $y=x$. Therefore, any upper bound for the left side is also an upper bound for the right, and we have
$$\sup((f+g)[A]) \leq \sup(f[A]+g[A])$$

The dual calculation applies for the infimum (can you see why?) and we get that 
$$\inf((f+g)[A]) \geq \inf(f[A]+g[A])$$